# Relation of two general series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that a positive series $\sum_{k} a_k$ converges (i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k < \infty$),
is it always true that $\sum_{k = 1}^n \sqrt{a_k} = o(\sqrt{n})$ ?
(By Cauchy-Schwarz, it is easy to get $O(\sqrt{n})$.)

Answer (score 4):

Of course: for fixed $\varepsilon>0$ choose $M$ such that $\sum_{n>M} a_n<\varepsilon$, then for $n>M$ we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^M \sqrt{a_k}+\sum_{k=M+1}^n \sqrt{a_k}  \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^M \sqrt{a_k}+\sqrt{(n-M)\varepsilon}
$$
by Cauchy–Schwarz.
Dividing by $\sqrt{n}$ and taking limsup we get
$$
\limsup \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k} \leqslant \sqrt{\varepsilon}.
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary,it follows that
$$
\lim \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k}=0.
$$